# Create a html wysiwyg editor for editing email templates

Tags: html, email, wysiwyg

The (web based) software I am working on needs a way for users to be able to customize an email template.

I'm familiar with TinyMCE et al. web based wysiwyg editors. However they strive to produce valid (x)html markup, with heavy use of style sheets. All of which won't render nicely in email clients (yes, I'm looking at you.. outlook 2007).

Is anyone aware of one that can be configured for generating email friendly html?

Comment: 6 years later and there still isn't anything, even more required now outlook has dropped support for margin. Dont think any developer wants to dare take on this project knowing how many issues there will be.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at livepipe http://livepipe.net/control

The TextArea tab in that page has a nice simple wysiwyg editor that might suit your needs. It is javascript based and uses the Prototype framework.

Comment: The textarea tab is a bit too simple, doesn't have many controls beyond basic formatting, uses markdown, rather than wysiwyg.

Already using jquery and wouldn't want to load in prototype as well either.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [fckeditor](http://www.fckeditor.net/) because it supports templates.  You could create several email friendly templates and have users start with one of those.

Comment: fckeditor renders `<span>` with inline styling when you try to add font colors, font size, or change fonts. Email clients like outlook and gmail do not allow this. What they implement is <font> tags. How to tweak fckeditor or tinymcs to achieve this?