# Tweaking WYSIWYG editor for web based email application

Tags: email, tinymce, ckeditor, wysiwyg, fckeditor

I have an email sending web application and for text formatting I need to implement a WYSIWYG editor for email body. I have tried Tinymce and fckeditor but the major problem with these editors being that they output `<div>` and `<span>` tags with inline style. Most email clients like outlook and even gmail simply rip off any css and hence they are of no use.

I went ahead with TinyMCE and used the following configuration for font colors:

```
<script>
    tinyMCE.init({
        theme_advanced_buttons1_add : "forecolor,backcolor",
        tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});
    });
</script>
```

As said above, I get `<span style="font-color:#ff0000">Text here</span>` when I try to add red color to a portion of text. This gets removed by both Gmail and outlook and what the receiver gets is black text. No fonts, no font colors. What mail clients understand is the old `<font>` tag.

My question: How can I tweak tinymce (or fckeditor) to output `<font>` tags instead of `<span>`? I could not find a useful solution in their documentation. It would also help if anyone can suggest any other email friendly text editors out there.

A similar question is here but without a solution: [Create a html wysiwyg editor for editing email templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354769/create-a-html-wysiwyg-editor-for-editing-email-templates)

Comment: FCKEDITOR is kinda old. Take a look at the CKEditor 4.x It have loots of options.

Comment: Try using 'color' instead of 'font-color' in your css.

Comment: @John: there is no css allowed in html for an email.

Comment: @Zeeshan You are incorrect. CSS Support is listed [here](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

Comment: The guide shows `font-family` and `color` as supported by webmail and outlook. However, as I have already mentioned the code above sent via phpmailer, it ddnt work in gmail and outlook both. However, `<b>` tags worked fine. I don't understand why. I will check the list mentioned in your link again.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an older post, but the current version of TinyMCE has a [legacyoutput](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:legacyoutput) plugin that will do just that. Just initialize with this option:

```
tinymce.init({
    plugins: "legacyoutput"
});
```

Comment: What to use if they remove this option by it's reference: `These elements should no longer be used for such purposes since they are deprecated in later XHTML and HTML5 specifications.`

Comment: @IvijanStefanStipić Yes, elements like `<font>` should not be used anymore, but most email clients are still stuck in the stone age.  That's why there's a `legacyoutput` option, for compatibility with stubborn email clients.  If you're not using TinyMCE for emails, then you probably shouldn't use it.

Comment: Yes I use it to build some email templates and that's why I ask. I adapt TinyMCE for amazone rules and works well but I'm afraid what if that suddenly stop working well in next versions of TinyMCE?

Comment: @IvijanStefanStipić Then don't upgrade?  You could check out their [github page](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce) and ask them.  Don't know why they would take it out, it's been in there for a while.

Answer (score 1):

There's a sample in [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)'s package that show how you can configure it to produce `font` tags instead of `span` tags.

You can find it in `ckeditor/samples/plugins/htmlwriter/outputhtml.html`.

Although, AFAIK and according to [Guide to CSS support in emails](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) you can freely use some basic styling, but it have to be inline styles.

PS. Recently I started a small project called [styliner](https://github.com/Reinmar/styliner). This library accepts stylesheet plus HTML and it produces HTML with inline styles. It's not ready yet, but in simple cases it may be already useful.

Comment: There are a few tools that have similar functionality already: [Premailer](http://premailer.dialect.ca/), [Inline Styler](http://inlinestyler.torchboxapps.com/) and [MailChimp Inliner Tool](http://beaker.mailchimp.com/inline-css).

Comment: I knew about the MailChimp Inliner, but it is a closed API. Didn't know about Premailer and Inline Styler - thanks for links. Luckily - none is in JS :P

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using php [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace all instances of 'span' with 'font'.

Simple example:

```
$output = $_POST['yourForm']; // or whatever variable the editor returns
$output = str_replace('span', 'font', $output); // $output now has all instances replaced
```

Because the editors are not designed for email, you'll have to run a bunch of functions on them (in addition to limiting their functionality) to output only email friendly html.

Comment: That was a useful suggestion, though will need lots of code to be added to correctly convert the HTML to old email friendly tags.

Answer (score 0):

@Captain Hypertext's answer correctly answers @Zeeshan's question, but won't fix the primary issue.

As @John mentioned in a comment above, the cause of the issue why the OP @Zeeshan's code wouldn't work in email clients is due to using a CSS property that doesn't exist.

```
<span style="font-color:#ff0000">Text here</span>
```

The above will not be coloured in any email client (nor web browser), as the CSS property    **font-color** is invalid (does not appear in any CSS specification).

```
<span style="color:#ff0000;">Text here</span>
```

The above will work in the majority of email clients and all web browsers as the CSS property **color** is valid ([since CSSv1](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#color)). This won't work if inside a link in older Outlook email clients though (2007 - 2012 iirc).

Answer (score -1):

You could define that text styling has to be set as a tag in tinymce:

```
tinyMCE.init({
        // Override internal formats  
        formats: {
            bold : {inline : 'b' },  
            italic : {inline : 'i' },
            underline : {inline : 'u'}
        },
    ...
}
```